# UI Router - Set parent to active for all child states when ui-sref is given as link to one child

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Hi I have created a AngularJS application. I'm using UI-router.
I have one main menu and then sub menu.
 Main menu I have something like

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li ng-class="{'active':$state.includes('home')}"><a ui-sref="home.main1">Home</a></li>
                <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="dashboard.dash1">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="report">Reports</a></li>
                </ul>
```

For one main menu *home* I have sub menu as

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
<li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="home.main1">Main 1</a></li>
<li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="home.main2">Main 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

And for main menu *dashboard* i have sub menu as

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="dashboard.dash1">Dashboard 1</a></li>
  <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="dashboard.dash2">Dashboard 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

In the above, the sub menus becomes active as per URL. but the parent menu is not becoming active.

In dashboard, I set **`ui-sref-active`** but the problem is the **`ui-sref`**I set to **dash1** state. So dashboard state becomes active only when dash1 is active, not dash2.
In home I tried using ng-class as you can see. But it's not working.

Here is the [plnkr Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/RlT41C0cOgcE8fy086S6?p=preview).

How to set the parent state active whenever child is active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<li ng-class="{'active':$state.includes('home')}">
```

The expression you're using with `ng-class` above is evaluated in the context of the current $scope. Your controller doesn't define anything on the $scope, so the expression fails.

You can do this to make it work ([plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/291T4hZhiFT6DJvNly3U?p=preview)):

```
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
  console.log($state.current.name);
  $scope.$state = $state;
});
```

The merits of putting a service on the scope are debatable.

Comment: @ShijuKBabu in addition, this subject have a big thread on the ui-router github https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1235 and they didn't decide yet how the ui-router "native" redirect for abstract state will works.